# Downloading Google Sheets worksheets as CSV files

Tags: .net, google-sheets

When attempting to download a published Sheets document as multiple CSV files, I am only able to retrieve the first worksheet. I would rather the code be self-contained without using the Google API. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible but you need to pull the document as a feed in order to collect the worksheet IDs.

```
$document = "<Google_Sheets_Document_Id>"

$ns = @{n="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"}
$feedXml = [xml](Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/$document/public/full").Content

$entries = Select-Xml -Xml $feedXml -Namespace $ns -XPath "/n:feed/n:entry"
foreach ($e in $entries)
{
    $href = Select-Xml -Xml $e.Node -XPath "n:link[@type='text/csv']/@href" -Namespace $ns
    $query = ([System.Uri]"$($href.Node.Value)").Query.Replace("format", "output")

    $e.Node.title #Sheet title
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/$document/pub$query" #Sheet URL
}
```

This will download the Atom feed and retrieve the worksheet titles and URLs for the individual CSV files from the XML document.